# How to mock async method in an interface with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, create-react-app

I have the following interface in TypeScript:

```
interface Something {
  getValueAsync: () => Promise<number>
}
```

I'm trying to create a mock instance with Jest. I've tried:

```
const mock : Something = {
  getValueAsync: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(123),
};
```

and

```
const mock : Something = {
  getValueAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(123)),
};
```

but my code keeps failing when I run the tests:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

   7 |
   8 |   useEffect(() => {
>  9 |     if (something) something.getValueAsync().then(setValue);
     |                    ^
  10 |   }, [something]);
```

The error does not occur if I create my mock with:

```
const mock : Something = {
  getValueAsync: () => Promise.resolve(123),
};
```

Note: this happens in a create-react-app. The code that fails is in a functional component and the value of `something` is retrieved via the context. The mocked instance is passed via the context provider.

**UPDATE**: the issue can be observed on this repo: https://github.com/gfox1984/jest-async when running locally (but not when using [the same repo on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-pine-m481d?file=/src/SomethingComponent.test.tsx) ¯\*(ツ)*/¯)

Any idea?

Comment: mock.getAsyncValue().then((value) => /* do something */);  ???? in your snippet something is not defined.

Comment: yeah I got that, getAsyncValue returns undefined instead of the expected Promise, that's my issue... question is why?

Comment: I submitted an [issue on the create-react-app repo](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11027) as I suspect that this bug is related to it.

Answer (score 0):

```typescript
const mock : Something = {
  getValueAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(123)),
};
```

is ok. Though for expected value you should use [`mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mock-property) property of the mocked function:

```typescript
something.getAsyncValue()

expect(something.getAsyncValue.mock.results[0].value).resolves.toBe(123)
```

[stackblitz playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-tprrhx?file=index.test.js)

Comment: Unfortunately, this code giving me the error. Note that I do not use `something` directly is my test, but the component that I'm testing does (and fails)

Comment: Added stackblitz link with working example. Run with `jest` or `yarn jest` in terminal console

Comment: I'll try to create a sandbox with the failing scenario and update the question.

Comment: And I'm gutted... my scenario works inside the [codesandbox I created](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-kalam-9srr8?file=/src/SomethingComponent.test.tsx) . Maybe it's something to do with the create-react-app, or i've missed something totally unrelated...

Comment: I confirm, the same code put inside a create-react-app fails ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I will update the question